# SFCC Salesforce Payments: is it possible to have GooglePay button on FireFox browser?

Tags: commerce-cloud, google, b2c, firefox

Do you know if it's possible to have **GooglePay** express checkout on **FireFox** browser (desktop or mobile), with configured GooglePay  in **Salesforce Payments**?
Look like it's not supported, but some articles in the internet says that GP will be supported by FF
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since GooglePay in Salesforce Payments implemented trough Stripe, we find out that Stripe doesn't support Google Pay for FireFox
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-testing
[image]